# Developing an Android pre-load type application which opens up market details page

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing a pre-load-type application... the desktop icon needs to take you directly to the market details page where you can download the full app. i can't seem to figure out how to go straight to the market, bypassing any kind of actual application screen.. the application screen loads for a split second, displaying the value from the android:label tag from the manifest... then the market details loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"` to the `<activity>` element for your launcher activity.

Step #2: Call `finish()` just after calling `startActivity()` to bring up the Market activity.

Comment: this was very helpful, thanks so much for giving this answer, it did exactly what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName);
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
startActivity(marketIntent);
```